# KivyMD DatePicker not resizing with screen size

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm not sure how to dynamically resize the MDDatePicker with the screen size, it doesn't adjust correctly like `Labels` and `Buttons` but rather adjusts erratically.

I couldn't find much on KivyMD documentation like there in on Kivy widgets.

You've got to click the Select Date button to open the Date Picker

py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
import mysql.connector
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class Information(Screen):

    def select_date(self):
        picker = MDDatePicker(callback=self.got_date)
        picker.open()

    def got_date(self, the_date):
        print(the_date)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [Information(name="information")]
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)

        sm.current = "information"
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kv file

```
<Information>:
    name: "information"

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "Test"
                on_release: app.root.current = "login"

        FloatLayout:
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                md_bg_color: 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: root.ids.nav_layout.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Select date"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.35, "top": 0.6}
                on_release: root.select_date()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you could try under `MDRaisedButton` putting this:

```
MDRaisedButton:
    size: root.width, root.height
```

or where ever you need to resize. The `size` commands format is `size: x, y` in kv lang